# DNS: Is it possible to do "query rewriting"?

Tags: networking, dns

I would like to "map external host names into my domain address space". **I need to do this in one go.**

For example if I define the following HOST mappings

```
HOST1.delegated1.my.example.com    ->  HOST1.domain1.com
HOST2.delegated2.my.example.com    ->  HOST2.domain2.com
HOST3.delegated2.my.example.com    ->  HOST3.domain2.com
```

what I would want to happen is for the DNS client to ask: 
  'resolve HOST1.delegated1.my.example.com' 
and for my DNS server to return back the resulting IP address(es).

I would prefer to actually obtain the result from the appropriate upstream DNS server to find out what is the actual IP for **HOST1.domain1.com** and return the result to the client (with TTL and all).

Additionally if the response is a CNAME I have to resolve it "locally" and only return the final result (IP or list of IPs) to the client. I should not be returning the CNAME, which would result in another DNS query being issued.

In other words I need to return an IP (or multiple IPs), not to return another name that the client needs to resolve. I need the resolution to happen by me.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is there some way to configure Bind or DNSMasq to do something like this?

The reasons for this requirements are a bit more complicated, but this is what it boils down to. Esentially the DNS client is unknown. Typically a Linux or Windows server or workstation, which will query another DNS server. That server will be configured to point to me for the resolution of anything under "my" subdomain. In this example anything that ends with .my.example.com. and I need to be able to resolve that name. In reality as stated that should be something like a CNAME that I should resolve (not the client). The reason is because the client is not able to resolve names outside of example.com. Or to be exact, the "main" DNS server(s) that the clients are configured to query are isolated and do not have connectivity to external DNS servers to query HOST1.domain1.com. Further I want to restrict which names or domains are resolvable. Hope this clarifies the intended use.

Comment: Why don't you want to use CNAME RRs, which are practically *designed* for this? (Mapping one RRname to another.) Please **[edit]** your question to include a rationale. (Also, you may want to change the term from "subdomain mapping" to "query rewriting" which would likely be closer to what you're looking for. The title caused at least myself quite some confusion.)

Comment: Thanks. I changed the subject as you suggested. If you mean why not use a regular CNAME record, the requirement is for all the resolution to happen in one go. To my understanding (and correct me if I am wrong) when a client issues a DNS query for HOST1.delegated1.my.example.com if this is defined as a CNAME, the DNS server would return as a response HOST1.domain1.com (rather than the IP address) and the client would have to issue a second query asking what is the IP of HOST1.domain1.com. Correct? This is the part I must avoid. The client must get the response in one try.

Comment: That depends on your resolver, and the relationship between the client and the resolver. I strongly suggest that you change the question to pretty much be what was in your comment just now: state the desired end goal (and perhaps provide some rationale for why that is needed), rather than focusing on a specific possible-solution that may or may not be the most appropriate one. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730) for more on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: It is possible using PowerDNS scripting. It is fairly simple.

Posting here a sanitized version of the Lua script

```
-- File: pdns-preresolve.lua
-- Description: This is a Lua script that pdns-recursor will invoke on each DNS resolution

-- References::
--   Lua
--  Programming in Lua - http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html
--   PowerDNS:
--  docs - http://doc.powerdns.com/md/recursor/scripting/#cname-chain-resolution
--  examples - https://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/browser/trunk/pdns/pdns/powerdns-example-script.lua

-- Mapping rules:
--  delegated1.my.example.com   ->  domain1.com
--  delegated2.my.example.com   ->  domain2.com


function preresolve ( remoteip, domain, qtype )
        print ("prequery handler called for: ", remoteip, getlocaladdress(), domain, qtype)
        pdnslog("preresolve:: query "..qtype.." "..domain.." from "..remoteip.." on "..getlocaladdress());

        -- "hard code" the IPs of our 2 NS servers here, so we do not have to setup the regular pdns daemon
        -- currently this IGNORES the qtype. It probably should not
    if domain == "ns1.my.example.com." then
        return 0, {{qtype=pdns.A, content="10.1.1.1", ttl=21600}}
    end        

    if domain == "ns2.my.example.com." then
        return 0, {{qtype=pdns.A, content="10.1.1.2", ttl=21600}}
    end        

        -- print("DISABLE the cache")
        -- I am not really sure we need this. We might possibly cache some queries. I had some issues initially with getting failures to resolve, but were caused by pdns-recursor config issues
        setvariable()

        -- we also might want to drop any other types of DNS requests that match our made up domain
        -- or implement the "replacement" only for 'A' records
        -- for example 'host' with no options automatically queries AAAA (28) and MX (15) type records
        -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types

        local myCname
        local section
        section = ""

        if domain:match("delegated1") then
                myCname,subs = string.gsub(domain, "\.delegated1\.my\.example\.com", ".domain1.com")
                section = "delegated1"
        elseif domain:match("delegated2") then
                myCname,subs = string.gsub(domain, "\.delegated2\.my\.example\.com", ".domain2.com")
                section = "delegated2"
        else
                pdnslog("Doing nothing for:" .. domain);
                return -1;
        end

        if subs == 1 then
                pdnslog("myCname = " .. myCname);
                return "followCNAMERecords", 0, {{qtype=pdns.CNAME, content=myCname, ttl=60}}
        else
                pdnslog("No match in section [" .. section .. "] for: " .. domain);
        end

        -- we do not know how to resolve, let it continue recursing
        return -1;

end
```

Also, here is the shell script to set this up

```
#!/bin/bash

# File: configure-pdns-recursor.sh
# Description:  Configure the pdns-recursor on CentOS 6.x
# Initial version. Not very well tested in terms of this shell script. It is more of a record of the commands I executed manually


sudo yum install pdns-recursor lua -y
# ...
# Package lua-5.1.4-4.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
# Package pdns-recursor.x86_64 0:3.7.1-1.el6 will be installed
# ...
# Installing : pdns-recursor-3.7.1-1.el6.x86_64
# ...

# make sure the daemon will be started automatically on boot
sudo chkconfig pdns-recursor on

# change syslog configuration
if [[ ! -e /etc/rsyslog.conf.orig ]]; then
    echo "Replacing /etc/rsyslog.conf"
    sudo cp -p /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.conf.orig
    # stop logging to /var/log/messages
    sudo sed -i 's/^\*\.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none[ ]/\*\.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local0.none /' /etc/rsyslog.conf

    # configure log files for PDNS
    echo 'local0.*                       -/var/log/pdns.log' | sudo tee /etc/rsyslog.d/pdns.conf
    sudo service rsyslog restart
fi


cd /etc/pdns-recursor/

# move the default config. Has many comments/explanations
sudo mv recursor.conf recursor.conf.default

# preserve the couple of settings from the original that we need
grep -v '^#' recursor.conf.default | grep -v '^$' | sudo tee recursor.conf

SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/pdns-preresolve.lua
LOCALBIND=8.8.8.8

# determine the IP of this server
IP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/^addr://')

# complete the setup
echo "
local-address=127.0.0.1,${IP}
lua-dns-script=${SCRIPT}
logging-facility=0
forward-zones-recurse=.=${LOCALBIND}
##forward-zones-recurse=amazonaws.com=${LOCALBIND}, powerdns.org=${LOCALBIND}" | sudo tee -a recursor.conf

# create the script before you start the daemon
sudo touch "${SCRIPT}"

# change the ownership to the user running this script, so we can edit it easily
SELF=$(id -un)
sudo chown $SELF "${SCRIPT}"

echo "MUST populate the actual content"
#vi "${SCRIPT}"

# start the daemon
sudo service pdns-recursor start


MYGRP=$(id -gn)
sudo chgrp $MYGRP /var/log/pdns*
sudo chmod g+r /var/log/pdns*


echo "make sure it is listening"
netstat -nau | grep 53; netstat -nat | grep LISTEN | grep 53
echo " or filter by the proc name"
sudo netstat -natpu | grep pdns

echo " if it is not running it probably failed to start"
echo " check the logs - /var/log/pdns.log "
echo "tail -f /var/log/pdns.log"

exit 0

# to test you could do something like
TARGET="HOST1.delegated1.my.example.com"
dig -t A $TARGET @localhost | grep -v '^;' | grep -v '^$'


for LOOP in $(seq 1000); do echo "Looop $LOOP"; dig -t A $TARGET @localhost | grep -v '^;' | grep -v '^$'; done > /tmp/test.run
```